# LINQPad LINQ To SQL Updates with Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, linqpad

Say I have the following query in LINQPad targeting a SQL DB (using C# Statement(s) mode):

```
var query = (from te in Time_Entries
            select new { te.Period, te.Company_Name }).FirstOrDefault();
```

If I wanted to update the Period value on the selected record, I would think that I could do something like:

```
query.Period = 5;
SubmitChanges();
```

But unfortunately, I get an error on the query.Period assignment line:

```
Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.Period' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Is it possible to perform an update this way or in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. Anonymous types can't have properties that can be modified. 
From the documentation:

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first.

It doesn't really make sense anyway. Anonymous types are sometimes very useful, but not when you need to use Linq2Sql entity tracking and updating...

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the prompt reply!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is already in the

```
select new {}
```

Even if it would not be an anonymous type, all it could be is an insert....

The rest is answered by walther in his answer.

Comment: Good point. The minute you use the new keyword you're instantiating a new object, it's kind of obvious that you wouldn't be able to update the original dataset. Thanks.